# Array só traz o primeiro resultado

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário onde será cadastrado as respostas e caso terá também um campo para marcar qual a verdadeira:

```
...
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">1.</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Respostas[]" class="form-control"></td>
    <td style="text-align: center"><input type="radio" name="Verdadeira[]" value="S"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">2.</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Respostas[]" class="form-control"></td>
    <td style="text-align: center"><input type="radio" name="Verdadeira[]" value="S"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">3.</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Respostas[]" class="form-control"></td>
    <td style="text-align: center"><input type="radio" name="Verdadeira[]" value="S"></td>
</tr>
...
```

Estou recuperando da seguinte forma para cadastrar no banco:

```
if ($_POST) {   
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["Respostas"]); $i++){
        mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO pe_perguntas VALUES(null,'" . $_SESSION["IdPerguntas"] . "','" . $_POST["Respostas"][$i] . "','" . $_POST["Verdadeira"][$i]."');";     
}
```

Só que se eu marcar a terceira pergunta como verdadeira, ele me retorna sempre a primeira resposta como a verdadeira e não a terceira. Veja abaixo o print():

```
INSERT INTO pe_perguntas VALUES(null,'2','Resposta 1','S');
INSERT INTO pe_perguntas VALUES(null,'2','Resposta 2','');
INSERT INTO pe_perguntas VALUES(null,'2','Resposta 3','');
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi da seguinte forma, não sei se é a mais certa:

```
...
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">1.</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Respostas[]" class="form-control"></td>
    <td style="text-align: center"><input type="radio" name="Verdadeira_0" value="S"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">2.</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Respostas[]" class="form-control"></td>
    <td style="text-align: center"><input type="radio" name="Verdadeira_1" value="S"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">3.</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Respostas[]" class="form-control"></td>
    <td style="text-align: center"><input type="radio" name="Verdadeira_2" value="S"></td>
</tr>
...
```

E no PHP:

```
$verdadeira[$i] = ($_POST["Verdadeira_".$i.""] == "S")?"S":"N";

mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO pe_perguntas VALUES(null,'" . $_SESSION["IdPergunta"] . "','" . $_POST["Respostas"][$i] . "','" .$verdadeira[$i]."');");
```

Comment: No ternário não precisa das `()`.

Comment: Reforçando o que o @dvd disse, o ternário sem os parêntesis fica mais fácil de ler.